# Checkbox isn't taking action til my cursor leaves it

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have about ten check boxes that each implement different functions. I am trying to make one master checkbox that will 
a) check all 10 checkboxes;
b) implement the functions in each

I have gotten one to work but for some reason, when I check it, the others aren't checked until I move my mouse off of the master checkbox (after checking it). Bizarre, right? Here is the code for the master checkbox and the sub-checkboxes. (I have to warn you that I am a little new to javascript and it's possible that this is terribly written. Advice in that direction also welcome.)

```
/*change all buttons of a single genre*/
$("a[id^="+genre+"_]").attr("class",  modereplacement+"Button" + " showButton");
$("a[id^="+genre+"_]").attr("onClick", function(index, currentValue){ return currentValue.replace(mode, modereplacement) ; }); 
$("#"+"all_"+genre+'_cur').attr("onClick",function(index, currentValue){ return currentValue.replace(mode, modereplacement) ; }); 

/*check all checkboxes*/
if (category =='All')
{
    $("#"+"alls_cur").attr("onClick",function(index, currentValue){ return currentValue.replace(mode, modereplacement) ; }); 
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 13 ; i++)
    {
        /*change individual buttons*/
        var currentgenre = allgenre[i]; 
        $("a[id^="+currentgenre+"_]").attr("class",  modereplacement+"Button" + " showButton");
        $("a[id^="+currentgenre+"_]").attr("onClick", function(index, currentValue){ return currentValue.replace(mode, modereplacement) ; }); 

        /*change Quick button*/
        $("#"+"all_"+currentgenre+'_cur').attr("onClick",function(index, currentValue){ return currentValue.replace(mode, modereplacement) ; }); 
        $("#"+"all_"+currentgenre+'_cur').prop("checked", (mode == "offx")); 

    }
}
```

And here is the HTML that implements the 'Check All' aka 'Watch All' buttons:

```
 <td><a  class='quickButton'>Watch All</a></td>
       <td><input type='checkbox'  id='alls_cur' onclick=\"watchgenre( $user_id,'All','alls', 'offx', 1);\" ></input></td>
       <td><input type='checkbox' $checkname  id='alls_fut' onclick=\"watchgenre( $user_id,'All','alls', 'offx', 2);\" ></input></td>
```

Thanks for any advice you are able to give

Comment: Is there any reason you are using inline JS and `.attr()` to bind event handler? Using jQuery's `.click()` would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am honestly not sure if I can do what I want to do with just 'click'. These checkboxes (individual and the master) act on a bunch of buttons on the page, turning them 'on' and 'off' depending on whether it's checked or unchecked. Those buttons themselves change colors when pressed/unpressed and also, importantly, update a SQL database each time they are pressed/unpressed. Can I do that with jQuery? Any pointers in the right direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/118/

the below shows a snippet of the code in teh demo. the demo is showing that there are 5 check boxes and 1 check all checkbox. each box, when checked, triggers its div to have a colored background. when unchecked, it's background changes to white.  the check all checkbox checks all the other check boxes and triggers their actions with the line: `$(this).trigger('change');`.  This line of code simulates a `.change()` event for each of the checkboxes

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox check1"/> Background gray <br/>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox check2"/> Background lightgray <br/>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll"/> Check All

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkAll').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('.chkbox').each(function() {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
                $(this).trigger('change');
            });
        }
    });
    $('.check1').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'gray');
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'white');        
        }
    });
    $('.check2').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'lightgray');
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'white');        
        }
    });
});
```

hope this helps!

btw, just in case you didnt know `.change()` or `.on('change')` is an event triggered when the state of the checkbox changes (from checked to unchecked and vice versa)

Comment: Wow thanks so much for this code. Weird thing: I tried it and it did the same delay thing in Firefox. THen I tried it in Chrome and it worked great! My website, it turns out, also works great in Chrome but not Firefox. I wonder what might be different about the way Chrome processes JS. I am going to work on changing it to use .change() instead as you did. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try to use events (like onclick ) in jQuery like this_

```
$("selector").on("click", callbackOrFunction)
```